# Publish internal SAML Application to mobile users in MS environment?

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, saml-2.0, client-certificates, intune

What is the most secure way to enable co-workers with mobile web and moble apps to access SAML 2.0 enabled applications that are hosted on our intranet. We will use MS Intune (MDM) to send certificated to the devices, so we prefer that those can be use for authentification. The internal applications will need claims from the local AD (Groups, location etc) on the SAML ticket. We already have a local ADFS.

I'm leaning toward Azure AD Application Proxy. Will it , together with its connector, support all the features we need, or is ther a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a good solution I think. You could configure your ADFS to use Certificate for primary authentication. If you deploy the certificates to the user group, then the certificates will only be applied on the mobile devices which have been enrolled in Intune as well as with user affinity of the specified users.

Also you can use Device based Conditional Access feature in Intune to make sure only devices which are compliant with your compliance policy will have access to the corporate resources.